# Excel sum going to Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I had a spreadsheet that worked fine. I copied this onto different tabs. Now when I sum a group of cells I get a zero as the sum. If I highlight the cells the sum function on the footer works correctly. If i have a sum already working if i then click on the formula in the input window in the toolbar and then click on the formula to see which cells are highlighted when i then press enter the sum turns to zero?

[image]

This was the formula working

then when I click on the formula and press return the sum goes to zero

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and add some screenshots so we can better understand what's happening.

Comment: here is the formula working

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that at least one circular reference exists.

When you create a circular reference, Excel will give you the error message, and, if it can, calculate a result and place it in the cell. However, any subsequent calculation of the spreadsheet will cause Excel to place a 0 in the affected cell/s.

This is what is happening. It can be very subtle, especially with follow-on effects from SPILL results. ( By "follow-on" I mean "not from the calculation itself, but from its very existence"... For example, try limiting how many  items in a SPILL range show by counting blanks in the display column, then using LARGE() to display one less of the SPILL results. Works fine, displays the desired results until a recalc whan it begins displaying zeros in the SPILL results.)

But... you don't have to take my word for it. Look at the very LEFT edge of your status bar ("footer") and you will see "Circular References: H125" in both of your (unhelpfully, identical) images. We cannot see anything in the region of H125, nor, of course, formulas anywhere that depend at some level upon that cell, but one wagers that, if you fix that situation, the rest will fall into place. Or at least be able to reveal the next flaw in however long a chain of flaws there are. (Zero more, hopefully.)

(Not much more can be added without more information. Probably lots more since one cannot tell ahead of time what an unknown region affects without being able to look at any cell it leads to.)

Comment: Thanks for the help - the first two images were before and after but I repeated the second image by mistake - sorry for that.   I cleared out all the circular references and all working fine again now.   Appreciate the support.  Thanks Gary